# Xamarin Change Button Text fails

Tags: android, xamarin, button

My Xamarin app has two buttons. Button A and Button B. Both can initiate long-running tasks. I would like to signify to the user that the task is working by changing the button text to "Working" and change it back when the task is over.

When I click Button A, I have code:

```
btnA.Text="Working";
```

But that doesn't result in the btnA text saying "Working".

If I include in the procedure which stats the Button A task:

```
btnB.Text="Working";
```

That works. When I do the opposite, i.e., update btnB with Working and at the same time update btnA to Working when Button B is pressed the opposite happens in that Button B's text remains the same and Button A's text is changed to Working.

I've tried just setting the button text directly or using

```
RunOnUiThread(() => btnA.Text = "Working");
```

Whichever button is NOT pressed, I can update its text but I cannot update the pressed button's text.

Comment: Why don’t you bind the button text to a property in the viewmodel using inotifypropertychanged?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to change button text when click and task complete, but I don't know where you modify Button Text, I do one sample about running long task and change Button Text here.You can see if requiring your need.

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btna.Text = "Wait";
        Task.Run(() => method1());

        Console.WriteLine("UI thread is not block");      

    }

    private async  void method1()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
         {
             for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
             {

                 Console.WriteLine("the data is {0}", i);

                 await Task.Delay(1000);

             }

         });
        Console.WriteLine("the task is done!");

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            btna.Text = "Done";

        });

    }
```

You can see I can change Button a Text when I click, and I also can change back Button a when long task complete using  **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()**

Comment: I will try it out in my app tonight. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Ron, If my reply resolved your issue, please remember to mark it as answer, thank you!

Comment: I'm rewriting part of the code, so I may use your suggestion, but it will be a while (a few days at least)